# Reducing number of variables for Independent Component Analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, independent-component-analysis

Say I have a dataset with $n$ observations of $p$ random variables. Since $p$ is "large" (mine is 72), I would like to perform a fastICA only on a subset of $k$ variables, maintaining the same number of sources.

My point is: do I lose something by not considering the other $p-k$ variables? 
The mixing matrix will change in dimensions, but besides that I don't see any trouble in finding the sources.

Comment: The dataset can be found here: http://www.keel.es/ and then choose keel data-set and then multilabel datasets..

Comment: I don't know much about ICA, so let me ask, what are the *sources* you are referring to?

Comment: Of course you lose something: how would you even choose $k<p$ variables out of $p$? Randomly? What people sometimes do, is to use PCA to reduce dimensionality down to $k$ and then apply ICA.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Ok, maybe a little description of the variables can give the idea of what I would like to do:

for each of the n songs I have 64 timbric features and 8 rythmic.
What I would like to do is to select the 8 rithmic and then perform ICA, finding 2/3 sources from which the 8(k) features are derived. It's like the cocktail party problem with 8 microphones and just 2/3 speakers.